# Add product custom options in rest/V1/orders

Tags: magento2, api

I want to get product custom options in ordered items by rest/V1/orders.
If i use searchCriteria, i received all custom options [image]

but in another way i can't resieved custom options. Which method i must extend ?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Alex yes i found

Comment: like this ? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243442/export-custom-option-via-rest-interface?noredirect=1#comment340370_243442 @omelandr

Comment: @Alex yes, extenison attributes
see my answer

Comment: @omelandr
this does not work for me .....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155902)

Comment: @omelander did you get option text value instead of id ?

Answer (score 4):

in my extension i've created file etc/extension_attributes.xml with content

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface">
        <attribute code="voc_price" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

create plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="custom_attributes_voc_discount" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\OrderGet"/>
    </type>
```

OrderGet.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class OrderGet
{
    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory */
    protected $orderExtensionFactory;

    /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory */
    protected $orderItemExtensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtensionFactory $orderItemExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
        $this->orderItemExtensionFactory = $orderItemExtensionFactory;
    }



    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $resultOrder
    ) {
        $resultOrder = $this->getExtensionAttributesItem($resultOrder);
        return $resultOrder;
    }


    protected function getExtensionAttributesItem(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order)
    {
        $orderItems = $order->getItems();
        if (null !== $orderItems) {
            /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface $orderItem */
            foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem) {
                $extensionAttributes = $orderItem->getExtensionAttributes();
                if ($extensionAttributes && $extensionAttributes->getVocPrice()) {
                    continue;
                }
                $vocPrice = '5';
                /** @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemExtension $orderItemExtension */
                $orderItemExtension = $extensionAttributes
                    ? $extensionAttributes
                    : $this->orderItemExtensionFactory->create();
                if($vocPrice) {
                    $orderItemExtension->setVocPrice($vocPrice);
                }

                $orderItem->setExtensionAttributes($orderItemExtension);
            }
        }
        return $order;
    }



    public function afterGetList(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection $resultOrder
    ) {
        foreach ($resultOrder->getItems() as $order) {
            $this->afterGet($subject, $order);
        }

        return $resultOrder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working for me :)

Comment: For me not working: Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\OrderItemExtension::getVocPrice() on this if line: if ($extensionAttributes && $extensionAttributes->getVocPrice())