# Export custom option via REST interface

Tags: rest-api, magento-2.2.5

We have created a product with a custom option (free text field). The customer enters data, now this data should be exported via
[image]
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/xml" --header "Authorization: Bearer $B" "https://shop.example.com/rest/english/V1/orders/105"

But I cannot find the data of the custom option in the REST result.

Is that normal?

Is it a bug?

Comment: You need to call custom Order API and make code in Customer Interface.

Comment: Do you mean Customer Interface or Custom Interface? I wish this would be in the standard API ...  Created an issue over at GitHub - somehow it feels like a bug but it might be more a obvious missing feature https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18227

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by creating an Extensionattribute and copy logic over from the core giftmessage attribute which also adds extension attributes to orderItems.

Comment: can u share your module code here?

Comment: No, sorry it's not open soure

Comment: can u guide me 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/316366/